# Tried to put Progress component on navbar but it will not display

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
#progressBar {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(0, 162, 255), red);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  opacity: 10;
}

#progressBarContainer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#progressBarContainer,
#progressBar {
  height: 10px;
}
```

I am new in react learner. So I face the problem my progressbar status not show on navbar. I use  top:0 ,opacity :10 ,and Transformscale property, position :fixed but it will no work so where put this please suggest me. It runs separately, but when I put above navbar component it will hide.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we could clearly understand your question.

Comment: I created progress bar component and it will call on header component but it will not show progressbar on scroll.so help me where is my code wrong to call progress bar component. if mistake in css so help me what is wrong

Comment: Can you please also share the `jsx`?